# how to get (display) one to many relationship tables

Tags: laravel-7

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 82 | jhon |

| id | name_id | file |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 82 | file.pdf |
| 2 | 82 | file2.pdf |
| 2 | 82 | file3.pdf |

how to join with query builder in laravel 7 ?

my expectations :

$data = [

```
     'id' => 82,
     'file_name' => [
                    'file.pdf',
                    'file2.pdf',
                    'file3.pdf'    
                 ];
   ];
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

You could just join the two tables and transform the query result to meet your expectations. Let's say the two tables named `tb_name` and `tb_file`

```
$queryResult = \DB::table('tb_name')->join('tb_file', 'tb_name.id', '=', 'tb_file.name_id')
    ->get(['tb_name.id', 'tb_file.file'])->groupBy('id');

$data = [];
foreach ($queryResult as $id => $item) {
    $data[] = [
        'id' => $id,
        'file' => $item->pluck('file')->toArray(),
    ];
}
var_dump($data);
```

Also, you can use `hasMany` if you don't mind there would be two queries to your database.

```
// In Name.php
public function hasFiles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(File::class, 'name_id', 'id')->select('name_id', 'file');
}
// ======

$queryResult = Name::query()->select('id')->with('hasFiles')->first();
var_dump($queryResult->toArray());
```